# Cloud Functions for Firebase Error occurred while parsing your function triggers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I had been trying to send emails to the users in Firebase using Cloud Functions for Firebase. I am referring to the repository of firebase function at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

I install all the node packages for the firebase email function as required and explained on the repository.
I edited TODO in the index.js file in functions as

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
    // For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/

// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
    firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="email@gmail.com" gmail.password="gmailPassword"
    const gmailEmail = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
    const gmailPassword = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);
    const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
        `smtps://${gmailEmail}:${gmailPassword}@smtp.gmail.com`);
```

When I try to deploy the function using the command

```
firebase deploy
```

It shows me the following error
[image]

Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Could anyone please help me out in solving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`functions:config`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#set_environment_configuration_for_your_project) is a command that you run with the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#cloud_functions_commands) from the command prompt, not from your Functions code.

So in your command prompt/terminal:

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="email@gmail.com" gmail.password="gmailPassword"
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen; Is there any way to load and set these configurations from environment file like *.json ?

Comment: Like this: https://www-staging.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-29-managing-development-environments.html